# Transferring a WHOLE netbeans GUI project

Tags: java, netbeans, gui-builder

Alright, so for a homework assignment I had to make a simple application with java swing. I used the netbeans GUI builder to do it and it works fine. However, when I zip up the entire folder (Documents\NetBeansProjects\Lesson 7) my professor complains that he doesn't have all the files. What other files could there be? I'm zipping up the whole folder that includes build, nbproject, src, test, build.xml, and manifest.mf. Is there anything else I need to zip up, or is my professor doing something wrong?

Comment: Get the Jar file that NetBeans makes and submit that. It's all in there.

Comment: he has netbeans - it's what he recommended for the course. He says he's missing "all the settings, etc., that went into the GUI builder"

Comment: he wants source code as well. I guess I already gave him that, but it won't compile or something. He keeps telling me to zip the whole folder, and I can't go up any farther. I'll zip all my netbeans projects for that class and then i'll zip all my documents. I don't know what he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans GUI Designer uses the:

> Swing Application Framework (JSR-296)

Netbeans keeps those separate as libraries (see the **Libraries** Item in the **Projects** view of Netbeans). Netbeans Libraries can be viewed under:

> Tools --> Libraries

In order to run your application, you will need to supply the '**appframework**' and '**swing-worker**' jar files so that they can be added to the classpath in order to run the application.

Comment: I'm going to accept this because I never figured out what was wrong, and it was a really specific odd-end question.